# In iOS 11 status bar shifts screen to bottom

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, statusbar

There is some trouble with status bar in iOS. Some apps (like navigators or enabled hotspot) double status bar height. And it shifts all content down. On the picture I have tried to set top constraint from grey UIView to Safe Area. This does not work.

[image: Example]

I have tried to use Safe Area with bottom constraints for this UIView but it also does not work.
When increased status bar is disabled there is no problem.

**EDIT**

There are constraints for this screen. All constraints have 1000 priority.

[image: Constraints are here]

Comment: It looks to me like either your height constraint isnt adapting to the smaller container size or your toolbar is pinned to the elements above rather than the bottom layout margin.

Comment: Can you show how the constraints are setup (either in Interface Builder or in code) as without knowing that how can we tell if they are incorrect.